# document.getElementsByTagName('*') does not recognize SVG TAG and give console error

Tags: javascript, dom

the problem is simple, `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` does not select the SVG tag and in the console it gives an error.

But if I erase the SVG labels, works correctly.

My Code:

```js
var Master = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

/* NOT WORKING TOO 
var Master = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getElementsByTagName('*');
var Master = document.querySelectorAll('*');
*/

var Vector = [];

for (var i=0; i < Master.length; i++){
  Master[i].className = Master[i].className.trim();
  console.log("Class > " + Master[i].className);
  if (Master[i].className != ""){
    var chaps = Master[i].className.split(/\s+/);
    for (var j=0; j < chaps.length; j++){
      Vector.push(chaps[j]);
    }
  }
}

//console.log(Vector);
```

```html
<section class="classMaster">
  <h1 class="title-1"><b>Title:</b> Anyone</h1>
  <h2 class="title-2">Title T2</h2>
  <p class="parrafe"><b>Strong:</b> Year 2019.<p/>
  <p class="parrafe"><b>Text:</b> Everybody.</p>
  <p><b>by: </b>StackOverflow</p>
</section>

<svg></svg>
<svg className="any"></svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M11.99 2C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zM12 20c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"/>
  <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  <path d="M12.5 7H11v6l5.25 3.15.75-1.23-4.5-2.67z"/>
</svg>
```

My JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/RenatoRamosPuma/Lbj14xg7/9/

What is the problem with the SVG tag?

Comment: Move `console.log("Class > " + Master[i].className);` before you try trimming it. Will see issue better

Comment: the problen no is the console.log

Is>: Master[i].className = Master[i].className.trim();

Comment: Renato, @charlietfl is teaching you how to debug.

Comment: hint: `Master[i].className` isn't always a **String** - in an SVG, it's an **Object**

Comment: may be use **getElementsByTagNameNS** ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagNameNS

Comment: @RenatoRamosPuma right...and when you log ***before it errors*** you see it isn't  a string that you can trim

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.

I'm going to edit my jsfiddle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `document.getElementsByTagName(...)`, `document.querySelector(...)` and `document.querySelectorAll(...)` all DO recognise SVG.

The error you get from your code is not because of that. The problem is because you use `.trim()` on an `object` instead of `string`. Well, I get the confusion.

For normal elements, `.className` returns a string. For SVG, however, `.className` returns a [`SVGAnimatedString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString) object.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

console.log('className of div: ', div.className);
console.log('className of svg: ', svg.className);
```

```html
<div class="normal"></div>
<svg class="special"></svg>
```

To get the `.className` of SVG, there is 3 ways:

**1: [`.className.baseVal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString#Properties)**

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

console.log('className of svg: ', svg.className.baseVal);
```

```html
<svg class="special"></svg>
```

**2: [`.getAttribute('class')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)**

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

console.log('className of svg: ', svg.getAttribute('class'));
```

```html
<svg class="special"></svg>
```

**3: [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)**

*Please note that [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) returns an object, not a string.*

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

console.log('className of svg: ', svg.classList);
```

```html
<svg class="special"></svg>
```

Comment: or `.classList`, which should anyway be preferred even for HTML

Comment: Thank you guys, I will try to implement the solution in a for(){}.

Answer (score 3):

ClassName of `SVG` is an `SVGAnimatedString` whereas `ClassName` of `HTML` elements is string,

So when you try `Object.trim()` you end up getting error that `trim is not a function` because trim is method is not available on objects

```js
console.log('svg element',document.getElementById('svg').className)
console.log('HTML element',document.getElementById('div').className)
```

```html
<svg id='svg' class="any"></svg>
<div id='div' class='someclass'></div>
```

You can use getAttribute and setAttribute [MDN note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className#Notes)

```js
console.log('svg element',document.querySelector('svg').getAttribute('class'))
console.log('svg element',document.querySelector('div').getAttribute('class'))
```

```html
<svg class="any"></svg>
<div class='someclass'></div>
```

You can use [**classList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
console.log('svg element',document.querySelector('svg').classList)
console.log('HTML element',document.querySelector('div').classList)
```

```html
<svg class="any"></svg>
<div class='someclass'></div>
```

Comment: or `.classList`, which should anyway be preferred even for HTML

Comment: @Kaiido yeah true,

Answer (score 0):

Use `<embed>` tag instead, works fine for me.